# Group by added time variables in sql server statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query that is working in a pinch but it needs to be better. I am learning sqlsrv and am struggling with the timedate stuff.

Basically I need to pull all the unique arrivals (which is schtm + duration) and show how many to expect each hour.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

This query shows every unique time like 5:30, 5:45, 6:00, 6:15 etc. I need it to be grouped by the hour so it would show 5 - 6- 7- 8 etc then the count below it.

```
<?PHP
$currentdate = date('mdy');
    $this_time = date ("D, M j, Y H:i");
    $current_date = date('n-d-y');
    $this_time = date ("M j, Y H:i");

    echo"<table width=\"100%\" border=\"1\"><tr>";
$sql =  "SELECT DISTINCT cast(cast(SCHTM as datetime)+cast(DURATION as datetime) as time) as Arrivals FROM admissions.patientinfo WHERE SCHDT ='$currentdate' GROUP BY cast(cast(SCHTM as datetime)+cast(DURATION as datetime) as time)";

        $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );

        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt , SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            $Arrivals=$row['Arrivals']->format('H:i');

            echo"<td align=\"center\">$Arrivals ";
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT PATNUM as Count FROM admissions.patientinfo WHERE SCHDT ='$currentdate' AND cast(cast(SCHTM as datetime)+cast(DURATION as datetime) as time) = '$Arrivals:00' ";
            $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' ));

$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($query);

            echo"<br />$row_count</td>";
        }

    echo"</tr></table>"
?>
```

Comment: Is SCHTM and DURATION not stored as datetimes? What is the need for casting here?

Comment: They are both time(0) fields. Casting is the only way I could get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql =  "WITH CTE1
         AS 
         (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, CAST(SCHTM AS DATETIME)), 
         DATEPART(HOUR, CAST(DURATION AS DATETIME))) AS Arrivals FROM 
         admissions.patientinfo WHERE SCHDT ='$currentdate')
         SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), Arrivals, 108) FROM CTE1
         GROUP BY Arrivals";
```

This query should will CAST both SCHTM and DURATION as DATETIME, add their hours and print as the column Arrivals. I put it in a CTE to show TIME only and GROUP it properly.

Comment: I'm not following the with CTE1 - how do you get CTE1?  I put this in as the sql and it breaks everything.

Comment: This is what I have. I get NO results on my page. If I put the query directly on the server, I get the results.
$sql =  "WITH CTE1  AS (SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, CAST(SCHTM AS DATETIME)),         DATEPART(HOUR, CAST(DURATION AS DATETIME))) AS Arrivals FROM admissions.patientinfo WHERE SCHDT ='$currentdate')
         SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), Arrivals, 108) FROM CTE1
         GROUP BY Arrivals";
  $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
      echo"<td align=\"center\">$Arrivals ";
  while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt , SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
   $Arrivals=$row['Arrivals'];